# How can convert this regex to R regex and regex R usage

Tags: r, regex

I tested with regex101 but my code does not work in R. What can I do? Please help me.

```
(?<=\[).+?(?=\])
```

I have includes `>XP_002499978.1 predicted protein [Micromonas commoda]` type of fasta file and I need `>Micromonas_commoda_XP_002499978.1` type of info.

I need to delete and change parenthesis info.

Comment: In R regex, you need to escape twice. Try with `(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])`. If you are using base R functions (`gsub`/`regexpr` etc) then also set flag `perl = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
x <- ">XP_002499978.1 predicted protein [Micromonas commoda]"
x <- gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\[)[^][\\s]*\\K\\s+", "_", x, perl=TRUE) # Replace spaces in [ ]
## [1] ">XP_002499978.1 predicted protein [Micromonas_commoda]"
sub("^>(\\S+).*\\[([^][]*)].*", ">\\2_\\1", x)  # Reformat the string 
## => [1] ">Micromonas_commoda_XP_002499978.1"
```

There are two actions here:

- `gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\[)[^][\\s]*\\K\\s+", "_", x, perl=TRUE)` replaces all whitespace chunks inside square brackets with a single `_`
- `sub("^>(\\S+).*\\[([^][]*)].*", ">\\2_\\1", x)` reformats the string.

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/98EhJU/3) and the [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/98EhJU/2).

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I prepend the trailing parentheses that I deleted?

Comment: @iremKahveci If you want to keep the brackets, capture them, `sub("^>(\\S+).*(\\[[^][]*]).*", ">\\2_\\1", x)`

Comment: I understand the logic now. Thank you very much

Comment: @irem. You are welcome, thanks for marking the answer. BTW, if you want to learn more about `\G` use, see [this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsGUbvW5hsE).